# How can I install .ipa file to iPhone simulator in Xcode version 9.X

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I have an iPhone simulator running on Xcode 9.

I have a .ipa file, can you please tell me how can I install it on the Xcode simulator (iPhone X)?

Comment: I don't think you can

Answer (score 4):

You cannot.  The simulator cannot run ARM code.

Comment: What if I have a Source Code?

Comment: Then build it for the simulator and distribute the app (ie: via tarball).  You can install it by dragging it into the Simulator window or using 'xcrun simctl install ...`

Answer (score 2):

For those came here, if you have the source code then I suppose you have launched multiple times your app during development. You can copy the file **yourapp.app** from **DerivedData** folder:
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/...your.app.folder../Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator

and **drag the file yourapp.app** to any other iphone simulator.